# How can I prevent name is not defined in (if) condition in python?

Tags: python

```
for f in range (3):    
    if f == 0:
        firstS = quantity
        x_first = x_axis
        if firstS>=secondS and firstS>=thirdS:   
            x_axis = x_first
        if secondS>=firstS and secondS>=thirdS:
            x_axis = x_second
        if thirdS>=firstS and thirdS>=secondS:
            x_axis = x_third
    
    if f == 1:
            secondS = quantity
            x_second = x_axis
            if secondS>=firstS and secondS>=thirdS:
                x_axis = x_second
            if thirdS>=firstS and thirdS>=secondS:
                x_axis = x_third
            if firstS>=secondS and firstS>=thirdS:   
                x_axis = x_first
                 
f=f+1
```

Now, I struck on the name of `secondS` and `thirdS` are not found suppose I know the quantity value. Because I have to store `secondS` value while the second iteration is working or `f == 1` and store `thirdS` value when the third iteration or `f == 2`. I know that in the first iteration, the does not know `secondS` and `thirdS` name. My current solution is to write `secondS` and `thirdS` = 1, then run and delete, finally run it again. Is there any way to prevent this error or any suggestion for coding? Thanks.

Comment: Give them default values before the loop.

Comment: Instead of different variables for each iteration, use lists. Then you can use the same code in each iteration, using `f` as the list index.

Comment: Instead of variables like `firstS`, etc., which are not only irregular as far as general Python variable naming conventions go (should be `first_s`) but are likely a sign you need a list as in `s = (x, y, z)` and later `s[0]`, `s[1]` etc. Even better, make a vector class so your code's more readable, as in `s.x`, `s.y` and so on.

Comment: Move your tests to set the `x_axis` outside of the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to just move your tests to set `x_axis` outside of your loop.

assuming you have `quantity` and `x_axis` defined in some meaningful way related to `f in range(3)` then you can do:

```py
quantity = 10 ## something more meaningful here
x_axis = 1    ## something more meaningful here

for f in range(3):
    if f == 0:
        firstS = quantity
        x_first = x_axis

    if f == 1:
        secondS = quantity
        x_second = x_axis

    if f == 2:
        thirdS = quantity
        x_third = x_axis

if firstS >= max(secondS, thirdS):
    x_axis = x_first
elif secondS >= max(firstS, thirdS):
    x_axis = x_second
else:
    x_axis = x_third

print(x_axis)
```

I might think about accumulating these values for `quantity` and `x_axis` in lists though. Maybe something like:

```py
quantity = 10 ## something more meaningful here
x_axis = 1    ## something more meaningful here

s_values = []
x_values = []
for i in range(3):
    s_values.append(quantity)
    x_values.append(x_axis)
x_axis = x_values[s_values.index(max(s_values))]

print(x_axis)
```

The shortcut in the second version being obtaining the index of the maximum value and using that index to get the appropriate `x_axis`.